# lambda function Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'cerberus'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, cerberus

I am trying to use Cerberus in AWS lambda but running into the below error when trying to execute the code. I created a custom layer and pointed it to zip file in S3 downloaded from [here](https://pypi.org/project/Cerberus/#files). Runtime env for lambda and layer is `python3.11`. Any ideas on how to fix this and use Cerberus in lambda?

> [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module
> 'lambda_function': No module named 'cerberus'

```
from cerberus import Validator
...
v = Validator(schema)
...
```

Zip file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the library to a target folder and zipping the contents.

```
pip install Cerberus -t <myfolder>
cd <myfolder>
zip -r cerberus-1_3_5.zip .
```